# Writing logs crashes for some users with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Is log file full or is this a threat issue?

Tags: swift

We have a crash in our app that occurred 231 times affecting 185 users. I'm not sure if the log file is somehow full or is this a thread issue.

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS 0x00000001052f77e4
>   NSClassFromString

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libdyld.dylib                       0x195c656c0 <redacted> + 16
1  libdyld.dylib                       0x195c65cd4 <redacted> + 52
2  libdyld.dylib                       0x195c65b54 <redacted> + 52
3  libdyld.dylib                       0x195c724f8 <redacted> + 132
4  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x195ba4c38 getPreoptimizedClass + 148
5  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x195b8f8d8 getClassExceptSomeSwift(char const*) + 20
6  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x195b90784 look_up_class + 100
7  Foundation                          0x196222b00 NSClassFromString + 200
8  Foundation                          0x196213264 _decodeObjectBinary + 1708
9  Foundation                          0x196212928 _decodeObject + 340
10 Foundation                          0x196122050 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] + 168
11 Foundation                          0x196121eac -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:] + 352
12 Foundation                          0x196121b04 -[NSCoder(Exceptions) __tryDecodeObjectForKey:error:decodeBlock:] + 96
13 Foundation                          0x196121a7c -[NSCoder decodeTopLevelObjectOfClasses:forKey:error:] + 108
14 Foundation                          0x196120d08 +[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClasses:fromData:error:] + 136
15 Foundation                          0x196167268 +[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:] + 116
16 NetworkExtension                    0x1a803f0a4 __64-[NEVPNConnection updateSessionInfoForce:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 512
17 libsystem_networkextension.dylib    0x19ad05e20 __ne_session_get_info_with_parameters_block_invoke.145 + 32
18 libdispatch.dylib                   0x195b2d610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
19 libdispatch.dylib                   0x195b2e184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib                   0x195ae01d0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1044
21 CoreFoundation                      0x195dde3c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
22 CoreFoundation                      0x195dd93b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004
23 CoreFoundation                      0x195dd88bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
24 GraphicsServices                    0x19fc44328 GSEventRunModal + 104
25 UIKitCore                           0x199e6e6d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
26 myapp                               0x104ba5da0 main + 19 (Log.swift:19)
27 libdyld.dylib                       0x195c63460 <redacted> + 4

com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x195c375f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x195c36a60 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x195dde068 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216
3  CoreFoundation                 0x195dd9188 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444
4  CoreFoundation                 0x195dd88bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
5  Foundation                     0x196118994 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
6  Foundation                     0x196118874 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7  UIKitCore                      0x199f0649c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152
8  Foundation                     0x1962490b0 __NSThread__start__ + 848
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x195b7d1ec _pthread_start + 124
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x195b80aec thread_start + 8
```

Based on this stack trace, it happened on line 19 of the class Log.swift, which is `handle.closeFile()`.

```
class Log: TextOutputStream {

    func write(_ string: String) {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let log = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("myapp.log")
        if let handle = try? FileHandle(forWritingTo: log) {
            handle.seekToEndOfFile()
            handle.write(string.data(using: .utf8)!)
            handle.closeFile()
        } else {
            try? string.data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: log)
        }
    }
    static var log: Log = Log()
    private init() {} // we are sure, nobody else could create it

}
```

Is this happening because it is called while not running on the main thread? Would this below solve it? Since I need accurate logging, maybe I should avoid `async` and go with `sync` instead?

```
class Log: TextOutputStream {

    func write(_ string: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let fm = FileManager.default
            let log = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("myapp.log")
            if let handle = try? FileHandle(forWritingTo: log) {
                handle.seekToEndOfFile()
                handle.write(string.data(using: .utf8)!)
                handle.closeFile()
            } else {
                try? string.data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: log)
            }
        }
    }
    static var log: Log = Log()
    private init() {} // we are sure, nobody else could create it
}
```

Comment: if logging is so important that you are ready to block the UI for it (and that's what will happen if you do it on main thread, especially in synch mode), why not invest into proper logging library (e.g. SwiftyBeaver) and not this home-cooked stuff? 

For crash, I'd first check the line with exclamation mark (e.g. do `guard let str = string.data(using: utf8) else {...`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Porting into SwiftyBeaver, looks like a great solution.